# How to access an interface in a non-exported namespace?

Tags: typescript

The [type definition for Traverson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/traverson) looks like this:

```
declare var traverson: Traverson.TraversonMethods;

export = traverson;

declare namespace Traverson {

    interface TraversonMethods {
        from(uri: string): Builder;
    }

    interface Builder {
        getResource(callback: (err: any, document: any, traversal?: Traversal) => void): InAction;
        // many more methods
    }

    interface InAction { /* doesn't matter here */}
    interface Traversal { /* doesn't matter here */}
}
```

It works well as long as I use anonymous functions as parameter for `getResource()`. However, I want to use a named function and want to define its signature properly. Hence I need to get hold of the `Traversal` interface - which is not exported.

I can work around it the following way:

```
import traverson from 'traverson';
export type Builder = ReturnType<typeof traverson.from>;
let b: Builder; // only used in next line
export type Traversal = NonNullable<Parameters<Parameters<typeof b.getResource>[0]>[2]>;
```

While this seems to work, I do not like the third line - declaring a variable, something that goes into the transpiled Javascript code, just to get a type declaration doesn't feel good.

Is there a better way to make the `Traversal` interface accessible to my code? (Beside opening a PR for the source of that typedef, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to put a slightly modified version into a separate type declaration file:

```
import traverson from 'traverson';

export type Builder = ReturnType<typeof traverson.from>;
declare let b: Builder;
export type Traversal = NonNullable<Parameters<Parameters<typeof b.getResource>[0]>[2]>;
```